# ¿Cómo obligo a mi pagina web que al recargarse esta siempre se vea hasta arriba? No funciona en google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Quiero hacer es que mi sitio web cada vez que se recargue se vea al inicio de mi sitio web, ya que al momento si me voy hacia abajo y recargo por alguna situación se recarga en el punto en el que se quedo y yo quiero hacer que se recargue hasta arriba de mi sitio web, ya intente las siguientes lineas de código dentro del index de mi sitio hasta arriba de todo.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});

$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```

No las use al mismo tiempo, cada una la use por separado y esas lineas de código las saque de este `post` en ingles:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664381/force-page-scroll-position-to-top-at-page-refresh-in-html

Ninguna de las opciones que venia en el post funcionaba y no sé si es un problema de google chrome, porque en opera si funciona y de hecho ya limpie las cookies de google chrome por si eso causaba problemas.

Comment: Instead of location.reload(), simply use location.href = location.href. It will not scroll to the previous position as location.reload() does.   te lo dijo la respuesta no refresque la pagina simplemente recarga la pagina

Comment: @JackNavaRow Estás en StackOverflow en Español :D

Comment: @fredyfx por eso coloque en español mas o menos la traduccion

Comment: @JackNavaRow pero si quiero que sea al momento del load de mi sitio web, cuando el usuario le da clic en la flecha semicircular de recargar de los navegadores.

Comment: por eso lo agrege como comentario por dudas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre la solucion, ya que `google chrome` requiere un pequeño tiempo de `delay` para poder hacer el `scrollTop`, ya que mi `scrollbar` estaba alterado con la propiedad `hidden`, encontre que para que funcione tanto en `opera` como en `mozilla` como en `chrome` necesito enviarle un tiempo diminuto para que este pueda aplicar mi movimiento hacia arriba:

Codigo de solucion:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {

   window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(0); 
}, 0);

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente forma

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); // para IE, FF
    $('body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow'); // Para Chrome
});
```

Sin animación y en una sola línea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('html,body').scrollTop(0);
});
```

Asegurate que en tu CSS o estilos del Body y HTML no tengan modificada la propiedad **overflow** como **hidden**

Comment: si tengo la propiedad de overflow en hidden pero es necesaria para mi aplicacion, ¿eso causa problemas?

Comment: Si puede ser, intenta quitar esos overflow y prueba los scripts

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta solo que cambie el codigo de jquery por codigo de javascript y le agregue un setTimeOut para que funcionara en google chrome